# How to implement Java 's -classpath in PHP?

Tags: java, php

In Java , if I want to run TheClass in example.zip ,I could type

```
java -cp example.zip TheClass
```

How to implement this feature in PHP somehow?

---

My final goal is that I want to use Java's ProcessBuilder run PHP file which is  packaged in zip file . For more information please click here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641845/set-php-search-path-environment-variable-in-command-line

Comment: Have you looked into phar archives? Maybe that's what you're looking for. I don't understand the usecase tho. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Finally I unzip it first